# LightGBM sklearn api doesn't play well with sklearn's gridsearch if you want early stopping and a pipleine transformer

Tags: scikit-learn, lightgbm

LightGBM's sklearn api classifier, LGBMClassifier, allows you to designate early_stopping_rounds, eval_metric, and eval_set parameters in its LGBMClassifier.fit() method. While it's convenient, it doesn't play well with a custom data processor and sklearn's Gridseach. Example:

```
ml_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('cdf',custom_data_transformer()),
    ('lgb',LGBMClassifier())])

# You can't throw in lgb__early_stopping_rounds here because that parameter
# is used during the .fit() method, not the instantiation of the LGBMClassifier()
params = {'lgb__max_depth':np.arange(3,10),
          'lgb__reg_alpha':np.linspace(0,1,num=11),
         }

rgs = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=ml_pipeline,
                         param_distributions=params,
                         n_iter=10,
                         cv=5)

# So we designate lgb__early_stopping_rounds in the RandomizedGridSearchCV
# .fit() method. but oour eval_set() will not have gone through 
# custom_data_transformer(), so the x_train and x_test will be very different.
rgs.fit(x_train,y_train,
        lgb__early_stopping_rounds=10,
        lgb__eval_set=[(x_test,y_test)],
        lgb__eval_metric='auc')
```

tl;dr: Has anyone got any tips on making LightGBM's sklearn API play well with sklearn's Pipeline with a custom data transformation step and early stopping with an eval_set?

Comment: I struggled with this as well and couldn't find a satisfactory solution either. I ended up writing my own version of sklearn's `RandomizedSearchCV` (or `cross_validate` in my case), which was explicitly pulling x_train and x_test through the data transformer before passing them to `LGBM`. Basically like in the answer you received. I had to give up parallelisation and compatibility with my other models and code.

Answer (score 1):

You can always transform the data for your `eval_set` manually:

```
x_train_eval = ml_pipeline['cdf'].fit_transform(x_train)

x_test_eval = ml_pipeline['cdf'].transform(x_test)

eval_set_manual = [(x_train_eval, y_train), (x_test_eval, y_test)]

rgs.fit(x_train,y_train,
        lgb__early_stopping_rounds=10,
        lgb__eval_set=eval_set_manual],
        lgb__eval_metric='auc')
```

Comment: There might be a small amount of data leakage here in this case. What you think?

Comment: @HeavyBreathing Actually, there might be _less_ data leakage than in what you were trying to achieve initially, if I understood your question correctly. Here `x_test` is separated from `x_train` and will affect your model training only when early stopping occurs. But if you manage to make LGBM "play nice" with `RandomizedSearchCV`, then `x_test` will be used twice: first for early stopping and then for selecting best hyperparameter.