# What is the correct way to fit LGBMClassifier using RandomizedSearchCV and StratifiedKFold with early stopping?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, hyperparameters, lightgbm

I'm using python 3.7.12, lightgbm 3.3.5, sklearn 1.0.1
I want to fit a LGBMClassifier model with random search, cross validation, and early stopping.
The only way I found for doing this is writing my own random search-cv function. I couldn't find a built-in way to make RandomizedSearchCV send the eval_set and early stopping parameters to the model **at each random search-cv iteration**.

Please note that I do not want to run randomsearch-cv without early stopping and then use the best param on another eval set.
I want to run with early stopping on each iteration of the randomsearch-cv.

I tried using callbacks, but only lgb.train function receives callbacks param. fit function wouldn't accept it.
I was expecting for the callbacks to work and make the RandomizedSearchCV object send the eval_set param with the validation fold at each CV iteration. The problem is that the callbacks param wasn't recognized.
I can use lgb.cv, but then I lose the random search component.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71579403/lightgbm-sklearn-api-doesnt-play-well-with-sklearns-gridsearch-if-you-want-ear), but there's no solution for the problem there.

Is there a built-in way to do that without writing custom functions, but only by using the sklearn/lgb objects?

Thanks!
DR

Comment: I had the same problem. As I commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71579403/#comment134507376_71579403), using the same `eval_set` for early stopping and model evaluation inside `RandomizedSearchCV` might be strictly speaking considered data leakage. I don't know if this is of any practical concern, because the leak may affect all candidate models equally and `RandomizedSearchCV` may return just the right model (but faster thanks to early stopping).

Comment: Have you considered using `lightgbm.cv()` (with early stopping) inside `RandomizedSearchCV`? From the theoretical point of view, nested cross-validation is the right thing to do, which was discussed on [stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65128). However, splitting a small dataset one more way give you training folds that are too small, whereas for large datasets the nested cross-validation may take too long.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. lightgbm.cv is probably the correct way to go. Unfortunately, sklearn's API isn't flexible enough in this case

Comment: True. One needs to see if wrapping `lightgbm.cv` into a sklearn compatible estimators (clonable etc.) is more work than implementing your own cross-validation search function. In any case, there seems to be no satisfactory answer to your question at the moment.